# How to calculate sum of multiple responses inside a loop using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have two loops as shown:

```
        for (var i = 0; i < nearPlacements.length; i++) {
           var meshInstances = nearPlacements[i].model.model.meshInstances;
var mat;
var matEach = 0;
for (var i2 = 0; i2 < meshInstances.length; i2++) {
    mat = parseFloat(meshInstances[i2].mesh.indexBuffer[0].numIndices / 3);
    matEach += mat;
    }
    console.log(matEach);
}
```

console.log(matEach); outputs data as:

[image]

How to display data as a sum of all responses? Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

its like what you did with `matEach` variable but outside outer loop.

```js
let total = 0;
for (var i = 0; i < nearPlacements.length; i++) {
  var meshInstances = nearPlacements[i].model.model.meshInstances;
  var mat;
  var matEach = 0;
  for (var i2 = 0; i2 < meshInstances.length; i2++) {
    mat = parseFloat(meshInstances[i2].mesh.indexBuffer[0].numIndices / 3);
    matEach += mat;
  }
  console.log(matEach);
  total += matEach;
}

console.log(total);
```